# Click and change handlers fire simultaneously on Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two functions for the same ID attached to a button:

**First Function:**

```
$('input:radio[name=phoneSelect]').click(function() {
    console.log('First function now');
});
```

**Second Function:**

```
$('input:radio[name=phoneSelect]').change(function() {
    console.log('Second function now');                        
});
```

On safari it works perfectly fine, when I click the first time I can only see the first log however on Chrome, when I click the button both logs appear immediately.

I need to have the first log showing on the first click but when you do the second or more clicks on the second log shows.

Comment: can you please share HTML too?

Comment: @vijayP I am still building that but I need certain html showing on the first click and on the second and more click html content changes. Since on chrome both `.click` and `.change` are working simultaneously it is not working right.

Comment: I was just asking for HTML to know how many radio buttons are there in group? Also if I have 3 radio in my group then `click/change` should be considered for each one...am I correct?

Comment: @vijayP there is alot of radio buttons and they grow dynamically not all the same as they are being gathered from a database.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at below code snippet. May be this will help you a bit.

```js
$('div.selectButtons span').click(function() {
    if($(this).data("alreadyClicked") == null)
    {
      alert("First function now");
      $(this).data("alreadyClicked", "true")
    }
    else
    {
      alert("Second function now");
    }  
  
});
```

```css
input[type="radio"]{
  display:none;
  }
span{
  width:30px;
  height:20px;
  border: solid 1px blue;
  
  }

.selectButtons{
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="selectButtons">
  <input type="radio" name="phoneSelect" ></input>
  <span>Select</span>
</div>  
<div class="selectButtons">
  <input type="radio" name="phoneSelect" ></input>
  <span>Select</span>
</div> 
<div class="selectButtons">
  <input type="radio" name="phoneSelect" ></input>
  <span>Select</span>
</div>
```

Comment: in that case just change `$('input:radio[name=phoneSelect]').click` to `$('div.selectButtons span').click` and it should work

Comment: PERFECT!! Many thanks for your help sir! Can you update the question so I can accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

> I need to have the first log showing on the first click but when you do the second or more clicks on the second log shows.

That's not what those functions do. `change` triggers when you change the value of the radio buttons (Selecting one of the options) and `click` triggers when you simply click any of the radio button options.

If you want to count the amount of clicks on the radio buttons just use a variable which holds the amount of clicks.

```
var clicks = 0;
$('input:radio[name=phoneSelect]').click(function() {
    clicks++;
    if(clicks < 2) {
       console.log('First function now');
    } else{
       console.log('Second function now');   
    }
});
```

Comment: Can I speak to you personally just to explain further ? I will then update the question accordingly... just not to fill the post full of extra details

Comment: Ask away here in comments

Answer (score 0):

How about...

```
//Register initial click event
$('input:radio[name=phoneSelect]').one('click', function() {
    console.log('First function now');

    //register on change handler
    $('input:radio[name=phoneSelect]').change(function() {
        console.log('Second function now');                        
    });

});
```

Comment: I have tried that, however it doesn't work as I want.